# Printing a box of numbers with perimeters that are the same value

Tags: java, for-loop

I need series of for loops to return a box like below depending on the values of `m` & `n`.

Should output:

```
1  1  1  1  1  1  1      
1  2  2  2  2  2  1    
1  2  3  3  3  2  1   
1  2  2  2  2  2  1   
1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Below is my code so far which uses a series of loops to split the box in half and either ascends or descends the value for both the column and row. Where I am stuck is trying to find a way to make these perimeters for the values. Another note that this should be able to work without using any if statements.

```
int m = 5; //column value
int n = 7; //row value
int column;

for (int row = 0; row <= (m / 2); row++) {
    //Ascending
    for (column = 1; column < (n / 2); column++) {
        int outputNumber = row + 1;
        System.out.print(outputNumber + " ");
    }

    //Fixed
    do {
        int outputNumber = row + 1;
        System.out.print(outputNumber + " ");
    }
    while (column < 0);

    //Descending
    for (column = n / 2; column >= 0; column--) {
        int outputNumber = row + 1;
        System.out.print(outputNumber + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

for (int row = m / 2; row > 0; row--) {
    for (column = 1; column <= n; column++) {
        System.out.print(row + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Current output for the code above:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1     
2 2 2 2 2 2 2     
3 3 3 3 3 3 3     
2 2 2 2 2 2 2     
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: So the number printed should represent the min number of  'steps' it takes to exit the matrix?

Comment: What should the output be when the matrix is really an array (e.g., 5 x 1 or 1 x 5)?

Comment: What is the do while loop for?  It looks like column is always >= 1, so it will only ever execute once

Answer (score 0):

Here is my result. I know that it is a bit complicated and quick written, however it solves your problem. I also tested it with other numbers:

```
int m = 5; //column value
int n = 7; //row value

for (int i = 0; i < m / 2 + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + 1 + " ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n - ((i + 1) * 2); j++) {
        System.out.print(i + 1 + " ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print(i + 1 - j + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
}

for (int i = m / 2 + 1; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m - i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + 1 + " ");
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < n - (m - i) * 2; j++) {
        System.out.print(m-i + " ");
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < m - i; j++) {
        System.out.print(m - i - j + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my understanding is correct that the perimeter tiles should be 1, and subsequently each tile should display the minimum number of 'steps' it would take to get there from outside the matrix.

I personally have a hard time picturing/following your solution, so I'm not sure if my suggestion will mesh with your understanding.

First, lets separate the construction of this matrix from the printing of this matrix. I think this keeps things tidy, but that's my style.

Lets say you have c columns and r rows in your matrix. So we'll iterate over every cell with a nested for loop.

```
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
        int distanceToEdgeOfRow = Math.abs(rows - (r - rows)); //this finds the number of steps to the nearest row end
        int distanceToEdgeOfColumn = Math.abs(columns - (c - columns)); //this find the number of steps to the nearest column end

        int shortestPath = Math.min(distanceToEdgeOfColumn, distanceToEdgeOfRow); //is it shorter to take the closest row exit or column exit?

        //the shortestPath is still off by one, so we need to add 1 to shortestPath to see what should be printed on this tile
        matrix[r][c] = shortestPath + 1;
    }
}
```